# Override lightbox handling of <a> tag

Tags: javascript, css

I have a web page that uses jquery.lightbox-0.5.js and a list-portfolio to build an image gallery. Below each image I have some text to which I would like to add a hyperlink. However, whenever I use the a tag it tries to load the page in the lightbox handler.

This seems to force any  tags used in the list-portfolio class to be sent to lightbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.list-portfolio a').lightBox();
    });
</script>
```

Here is how it is used:

```
<div class="list-portfolio">
    <a href="site_images/meet_the_dogs/Sassy.jpg" title="Sassy"><img src="site_images/meet_the_dogs/Sassy_small.jpg" alt="Sassy" width="150" height="150" class="img-inside"/></a>              
    <h3 style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:0;" >Sassy</h3>
    <p><strong>Breed: </strong>Border Collie</p>
    <p><strong>Handler: </strong>Richard Mansfield</p>              
    <a href="sponsor-a-dog.php"><font color="#ff6600"><strong><em>Available for sponsorship</em></strong></font></a>
</div>
```

Clicking on the the image displayed by this brings up the larger image in lightbox - which is the correct behaviour. I've now added the a tag on the "Available for sponsorship" text and it is that a tag that I want to force to change the whole page, or via _blank open a new tab. At present, it tries to load the page in the lightbox loader which of course fails.

Question is - how do I override the launching of lightbox WITHOUT breaking out to a new  and therefore messing up the whole layout?

Comment: Providing a jsFiddle of your code would be really helpful.

Comment: ..also `<font>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 0):

If first `a` element in `.list-portfolio` is your LightBox element, you can try below code.

`$('.list-portfolio a:first').lightBox();`

else add a class to element which you want assign for LightBox.

Comment: BTW - is there such a thing as first and second?

Comment: actually that doesn't work to good - using a:first only catches the first image. subsequent images in the gallery get handled by the non-lightbox link so just display on a new page, not within lightbox

Comment: `:first` and `:last` selectors are there, if you want other you can use `nth` selector.

Comment: If you could set up a fiddle that will be helpful to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the Jquery selector more specific.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.list-portfolio a:first').lightBox();
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.list-portfolio a').first().lightBox();
    });
</script>
```

This will select the first link only.

Ideally of course, it would be preferable to have a class on each "lightbox" link that you could target with JQ rather than relying on the HTML structure.

Say,

```
<a class="light-link" href="site_images/meet_the_dogs/Sassy.jpg" title="Sassy">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.list-portfolio a.light-link').lightBox();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may open the Lighbox on image links only:

```
/* Open the Lightbox on all image links */
jQuery('a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".gif"]').lightBox();

/* Open the Lightbox on all image links inside .list-portfolio */
jQuery('.list-portfolio a[href$=".jpg"],.list-portfolio a[href$=".png"],.list-portfolio a[href$=".gif"]').lightBox();
```